# API Gateway Load Testing: IIS Outperforms Direct Backend Calls

Tags: performance, iis, load-testing, api-gateway

#### Context

- We have internal APIs hosted on a private network.
- Considering implementing an API gateway.
- Conducted load testing to evaluate performance under different scenarios.

#### Additional Information

- Load testing conducted with 100 virtual users for 1 minute. Results are in average response time in ms
- Each VM configurations are identical across the network.
- IIS servers perform only URL rewrite and proxying.
- No Caching Implemented in IIS Proxy Servers. Each request is forwarded to the backend (checked the backend logs)
- All requests are processed and returned by the backend. No static content.
- Custom Node JS api gateway is very simple one that just proxy the request. Nothing more

#### Testing Scenarios

1. Direct Backend Calls: ~2300ms
2. Calls through First IIS Proxy Server: ~800ms
3. Calls through Second IIS Proxy Server: ~400ms
4. Calls through Node JS API Gateway: ~2600ms

#### Key Observations and Questions

- IIS Proxy Servers Significantly Outperform Direct Backend Calls:

  - Even single requests are faster through IIS (50ms vs. 100ms).
- Why is this performance difference occurring?
- Why is the second IIS proxy server faster than the first? This is faster for both concurrent and single requests.
- Node JS API Gateway Slower than Direct Backend Calls:

  - Likely due to inefficient handling of concurrent requests. Even for single request, it is slower than IIS.

#### Considering IIS as API Gateway

- Given its superior performance, could IIS serve as a viable API gateway?
- Is this a common industry practice, especially for monolithic applications?

#### Proposed Architecture

- Use **api.xyz.com/{app-name}** as the endpoint for all applications.
- IIS would handle routing and proxying to the relevant backends.

#### Seeking Input

- Any insights into the observed performance results?
- Recommendations or concerns regarding using IIS as an API gateway?
- Alternative approaches to consider?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS proxy server may have some optimizations for requests, such as request reuse, caching, or more efficient connection management, which may provide performance advantages. IIS is a mature server software with strong performance and security. IIS can efficiently handle routing and proxies and provide load balancing capabilities, making it a suitable choice as an API gateway.

In some scenarios, it is common industry practice to use IIS or other mature server software as an API gateway. Such architectures are generally easy to maintain and extend.

For other alternatives, consider using specially designed API gateway software, such as NGINX, which not only serves the role of API gateway well, but also acts as a reverse proxy, load balancer, and web server for existing HTTP traffic.